# How to remove multiple instances of a program

Tags: linux, delete

I am trying to use [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but when I run

mkvirtualenv xyz
I get the message

virtualenvwrapper could not find /home/YOUR_USERNAME/.local/bin/virtualenv in your path

In fact virtualenvwrapper is at that location and it is in my $PATH variable

> /home/jeff/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/home/jeff/.scripts:/home/jeff/.local/bin/virtualenv
> [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274642/error-virtualenvwrapper-could-not-find-virtualenv-in-your-path)

I've looked at all the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274642/error-virtualenvwrapper-could-not-find-virtualenv-in-your-path) but none of them work for me. When I run

sudo find / -name "virtualenv"
I find that it appears multiple times

```
/usr/bin/virtualenv
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualenv
/home/jeff/.local/bin/virtualenv
/home/jeff/.local/share/virtualenv
/home/jeff/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualenv
```

so I'm guessing there's some sort of conflict

I've decided to remove virtualenvwrapper. How can I remove them all safely and consistently?

I'm using Manjaro

Comment: Is the file executable?

Comment: Yes. it is an executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by following one of the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274642/error-virtualenvwrapper-could-not-find-virtualenv-in-your-path)

In the end of my .bashrc I added the following rows (remember to put your username in the YOUR_USERNAME field):

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/home/YOUR_USERNAME/.local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

But in my case *virtualenvwrapper.sh* is in */usr/bin/*

So I changed the line accordingly